# How to define resource bundles from WEB-INF\classes in faces-config.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2, resourcebundle, faces-config, web-inf

To declare a resource bundle in the `faces-config.xml` I always put them into `\src\main\resources\com\company\messages.properties` and reference them like this:

```
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>com.company.messages</base-name>
  <var>messages</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

But as far as I know property files can be also put into the `\WEB-INF\classes` directory. Is there a possibility to also declare these files in `faces-config.xml`? Because they don't have a package name.

Comment: Build your project and take a look in the `WEB-INF\classes\com\company` dir. You should see your `messages.properties`. Maven actually builds it to the class path. Anything in a `src\main\resources` get built to the root of the class path, in the case of a webapp `WEB-INF\classes`